# CSS Hover property

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to make a CSS dropdown menu but just with CSS to keep it simple, so i have a `UL` structured nav menu like so:

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="source/home.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="challenge">placeholder</a></li>
        <li>PVP</li>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li>PVE</li>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li>Other Services</li>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="source/contact.php">placeholder</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now, i have hidden the class "inner" with Display:none. And i want to make it so when a certain parent li is hovered then that relevant inner will appear. hows is the best way i can do this? please let me know guys, or maybe you have a better way of making a dropdown?

Comment: Please add your css, or make a JSFiddle of it

Comment: I somehow have a feeling you could solve this by doing the following in your browser: `F6` -> type "CSS dropdown menu" -> `ENTER`

Comment: I agree you should search for answers on the Internet before asking

Answer (score 1):

Your html is not valid.

Do not close the "li" so early

```
    <li>PVE</li>
        <ul class="inner">
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
        </ul>
```

correct html is:

```
    <li>PVE
        <ul class="inner">
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
            <li><a href="source/placeholder.php">placeholder</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

and the css now:

```
.navbar li {
    position: relative;
}
.navbar ul.inner {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px; // edit it
    left: 0px; // edit it
}
.nav li:hover ul.inner {
    display: block;
}
```

i hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you need to put your inner menus inside the `li` elements so you would be able to align them.

next you would want to set the position of the inners to `absolute` so it would not mess up the navbar when they drop down.

and then a few cosmetic touches and here is an example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/73Nk9/)

Answer (score 0):

You could go here and create a pure css menu, very quickly and easily: http://cssmenumaker.com/pure-css-menus

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/NZ6EF/

**HTML**

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Widgets</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Menus</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
         <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Location</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#cssmenu {
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid #6b6363;
  background: #6b6363;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  padding: 1px 0;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 21px;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  font: normal 8pt verdana, arial, helvetica;
}
#cssmenu > ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 148px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li a:link,
#cssmenu > ul li a:visited {
  padding: 4px 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #6b6363;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 148px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu > ul li a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul li a:active {
  padding: 4px 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #928989;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 146px;
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px 1px 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 146px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 21px;
  left: -1px;
  border: 1px solid #6b6363;
  border-top: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li {
  clear: left;
  width: 146px;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li a:link,
#cssmenu > ul li ul li a:visited {
  clear: left;
  background: #6b6363;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 146px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li:hover a,
#cssmenu > ul li ul li a:active,
#cssmenu > ul li ul li a:hover {
  clear: left;
  background: #928989;
  padding: 4px 0;
  width: 146px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li ul.navigation-3 {
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 145px;
  top: -2px;
  padding: 1px 1px 0 1px;
  border: 1px solid #6b6363;
  border-left: 1px solid #6b6363;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 900;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li:hover ul.navigation-3 {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu > ul li ul li ul.navigation-3 li a:link,
#cssmenu > ul li ul li ul.navigation-3 li a:visited {
  background: #6b6363;
}
```